# SCCM Collection in DB

Tags: sccm

Is there information in the SCCM database about the date of adding a computer object to a given sccm collection?
I have write the SQL Query:

```
    select v_R_System.Name0 as MemberName, v_Collection.Name as CollectionName, v_Collection.LastMemberChangeTime, v_Collection.LastChangeTime  from v_FullCollectionMembership 
Inner JOIN v_R_System on v_FullCollectionMembership.ResourceID = v_R_System.ResourceID 
Inner JOIN v_Collection on v_FullCollectionMembership.CollectionID = v_Collection.CollectionID 
Where  v_Collection.Name like '%My SCCM Collection%'
```

Of course, the result concerns the modification of the collection itself, not the date of adding a computer object to this collection. 
Thanks for any advice, where this information is or how I can get it.

Comment: Without knowing your particular sccm system, it is impossible to answer this question.

Comment: Why is this? I would say there are lots of views and tables that are the same with every single sccm installation and this would be a standard column if it was possible. Unfortunately I know of no way to find this information. Briefly looked into it myself some time ago, but without success.